# Crash on Logging in

Tags: bug, android-app

Using the Official Android App, and my Asus Transformer 700 tablet in Landscape mode, I tried using the App. I launched the app, then selected Google (my OpenID Provider), accepted the request, then the system logged in and it crashed. Reproduced. Turned tablet into Portrait mode. Logged in without an issue, and am able to put it back into Landscape mode to type this question

Comment: So you mean it crashes in "landscape" mode?

Comment: Just when starting up. I can start in portrait mode, then switch to landscape without a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed as of the September 11, 2013 update. Can start it on both my cell phone and tablet in Landscape mode. Version 0.1.30

Comment: You should mention the version number. You can see it by clicking the options/menu button on the device and going to help.